# Can a decrement function be implemented from these four limited functions?

Tags: algorithm, math, assembly

How can I implement (if possible) a decrement function `dec(x){x--}` using only:

- increment(x) [x++]
- assign(x,y) [x=y]
- zero(x) [x=0]
- loop(x) [run whatever is inside the loop x times]

I cannot use for/while loops or basic operators such as `+,-,/` -- only the above four functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup: just write a loop with an off-by-one "error".
Count from 1 to x, but save the *previous* value of your zero-based loop index.

```
dec(x):
    zero(y)
    loop(x) {
        assign(z, y)
        increment(y)
    }
```

Comment: Many things look trivial *after* someone else finds them.  Some of the interview problems I've missed ... :-)